# R setting column name on do.call(rbind)

Tags: r, xts

In summary, I am looking to add a cumulative volume column to an XTS object.  However, upon calling `do.call(rbind...` I find the original XTS gets overwritten.

```
# Reproducible example data
foo <- rnorm(5)
bar <- seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), length = 5, by = "days")
foobar <- xts(x = foo, order.by = bar)
names(foobar)[1] <- "Volume"
# My processing ...
foobar_months <- split(foobar[,"Volume"],f="months")
foobar_vol_mtd <- lapply(foobar_months,FUN=cumsum)
# This is what is not working for me because Volume overwrites original Volume
foobar <- do.call(rbind,foobar_vol_mtd)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what is the question exactly? Which part of the code is not behaving as expected?

Comment: @RonakShah I want to merge cumsum Volume with the original XTS table.  But the "new" Volume overwrites the XTS.  I just want a new column.

Comment: If you want a "new" column, `rbind` is not the answer. `rbind` appends rows. Maybe use `cbind` or `merge`

Comment: @R.Schifini I tried merge but couldn't figure out how to rename on merge ?  Sorry, I'm a bit of an R-newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `do.call(rbind, list)` will do an rbind of all the list elements. You are not appending that list to the original.  What you could do is:

```
foobar2 <- do.call(rbind,foobar_vol_mtd)
foobar <- rbind(foobar, foobar2)
```

rbind all elements in that list together and then rbind the result to the original.

Result:

```
               Volume
1970-01-01  0.8995890
1970-01-01  0.8995890
1970-01-02 -0.5057975
1970-01-02  0.3937916
1970-01-03 -0.1861275
1970-01-03  0.2076641
1970-01-04 -1.1641303
1970-01-04 -0.9564663
1970-01-05  0.3157536
1970-01-05 -0.6407127
```

Results will vary because of `rnorm(5)` and no seed set.

**Append as new columns**

As I said, `rbind` appends new rows and all columns should be the same. If you want to append as a new column then try:

```
foobar2 <- do.call(rbind,foobar_vol_mtd)
foobar3 = merge(foobar, foobar2)
```

My result for this case is (new random values, so don't compare to above):

```
                Volume  Volume.1
1970-01-01  1.96291153 1.9629115
1970-01-02 -0.41771710 1.5451944
1970-01-03 -0.08827657 1.4569179
1970-01-04 -0.57243569 0.8844822
1970-01-05 -0.06093953 0.8235426
```

Then change the column name with `names(foobar)[2] = "new_name"`.

You could also rename before the merge:

```
foobar2 <- do.call(rbind,foobar_vol_mtd)
names(foobar2) = 'newname'
foobar3 = merge(foobar, foobar2)
```

And the merge will be done by the time index as before.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. But how do I avoid the naming conflict on merge ?